# Can't use linkopts when building libpqxx using Bazel

Tags: c++, cmake, bazel

I am trying to use Bazel with [libpqxx](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx), which does not have native Bazel support. Rather than trying to write my own BUILD file, I am using [rules_foreign_cc](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc) cmake() to translate the provided CMakeLists.txt, and this builds a library named pqxx and links a static library libpqxx-7.7.a. When I try to add this as a dependency to a cc_binary, it is able to see all the headers, but is not able to run the program.

When installed locally, gcc requires the libraries -lpqxx -lpq (the C++ and C bindings). Locally, all the commands work fine: For example: `g++  -L/usr/local/lib -lpqxx -lpq foo.cpp` where /usr/local/lib is where the library was installed. I cannot duplicate this behavior in Bazel.

I can see that there is a libpqxx-7.7.a file in bazel-bin, but adding the path from "$(bazel info bazel-bin)/workspace/libpqxx-7.7.a" throws a error: `ld: library not found for -lpqxx`.

Leaving the link options out produces

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>
> "_ASN1_STRING_get0_data", referenced from:
> _pgtls_verify_peer_name_matches_certificate_guts in libpq.a(fe-secure-openssl.o)
> "_ASN1_STRING_length", referenced from:
> _pgtls_verify_peer_name_matches_certificate_guts in libpq.a(fe-secure-openssl.o)
> "_BIO_clear_flags", referenced from:
> _my_sock_write in libpq.a(fe-secure-openssl.o)
> _my_sock_read in libpq.a(fe-secure-openssl.o)

which I believe is a linking error. I am new to C++, and am trying to translate the CMakeLists to work with Bazel. Where am I building my cmake wrong?

**WORKSPACE**

```
http_archive(
    name = "libpqxx",
    url = "https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx/archive/refs/heads/master.zip",
    build_file_content = _ALL_CONTENT,
    strip_prefix = "libpqxx-master",
)
```

**BUILD**

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary", "cc_library")
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "cmake")

cmake(
    name = "pqxx",
    cache_entries = {
        "DPostgreSQL_ROOT=": "/Library/PostgreSQL/14", 
        "DSKIP_BUILD_TEST": "on"
    },
    lib_source = "@libpqxx//:all_srcs",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    out_static_libs = ["libpqxx-7.7.a"],
    targets = ["pqxx"]
)


cc_binary(
    name = "database_tester",
    srcs = ["database_access.cpp"],
    deps = [
          ":pqxx",
      ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you tried to link the static `libpq` to your binary. In that case, you need to provide all static libs which `libpq` depends.

According to the error log, the linker can't solve `openssl` functions. So make sure you have installed `openssl` on your system and provide its static lib to `cc_binary` as deps.